# CPI too large while using Version 0 TX as inner instruction

Tags: versionedtransactions

I have an instruction that uses more than 1280 bytes that successfully runs as a normal call using Versioned Transactions. When I try to call it as a CPI it gives me a "Inner instruction too large error". Is there a way to similarly compress accounts via LUT for CPI's?

Answer (score 2):

Appears increased CPI size is on Testnet, will wait for the new release.